# Android - Custom Button gets stuck "Pressed"

Tags: android, button

I've created a custom button in my Android app that has basically two different views.  There is an image for when the button isn't being pressed and another image for use while it is being pressed.  Below is how I've implemented the button and how it responds to the user.

```
private void registerListeners() {

    calcButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            calcButton.requestFocusFromTouch();
            calcButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.calc_button_pressed);
            return false;
        }
    });

    calcButton.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            calcButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.calc_button_not_pressed);
        }
    });

    calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {           
            mathCalculation();
            calcButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.calc_button_not_pressed);
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is that there is a "bug" where if the user touches the button and drags their figure off the button the button stay pressed down.  The one work around I've implemented above is the "setOnFocusChangeListener" so once the user select something it else it will pop back up.

I want to have it so the button pops back out when the user drags there touched figure off the button.

All suggestions are greatly appreciated!!!

Thank you,

Comment: P.s... if anyone wants to see what is happening in action just search for myProfit in the android market.  It will be the only app that pops up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to write a separate button class to get that behavior, you can implement it through a drawable xml. Have this in your xml and set it as the background for your button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/calc_button_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/calc_button_not_pressed" />
</selector>
```

Comment: hmmm.  I have no clue how to implement that.  I just started developing for android about a month ago and have a lot to learn still.  When and where do I implement the drawable xml?  

sorry for being such a noob.

Comment: OK I figured out how to use it.  I created drawable xml in the hdpi folder.  I called it calc_button and i called it in my "setOnTouchListener".  It worked perfectly!

I have one question though.  Do I need to create this same drawable xml in the mdpi and ldpi folders?

Comment: hey Kevin, glad it worked. You shouldn't need to do that because according to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html the `drawable` resource folder is the only one that can 'magically' get the resources from the various folders without having to declare the "default" values. Otherwise just to be safe you can put the xml you created under the `drawable` folder and remove it from `drawable-hdpi`. Have a read through the localization link I sent you, it explains the reasons for using the configs for the different resources folders.

Answer (score 3):

In your onTouch method, check for the event action.

- If it's MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, then proceed as you have.
- If it's ACTION_UP or ACTION_CANCEL, then call `calcButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.calc_button_not_pressed);`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Answer (score 1):

You Could use use `onTouch`. Then use the `ACTION_OUTSIDE` which is fired when the users touch moves out the the bound of the view.

Edit 1: to be more specific:

```
OnTouchListener(MotionEvent e) {
   switch(e.getAction()) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE: // switch the image if the button
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the click event "happens" only when touching and *releasing*. If you're touching and moving outside that's not a click.

To do what you want use a [StateListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html), it's made just for that.